# Real-world uses of MySQL savepoints in web services?

Tags: mysql, web-services, transactions, nested-transactions

Does anyone have experience they can share using MySQL [savepoints](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/savepoint.html) (directly or via an ORM), especially in a non-trivial web service?  Where have you actually used them?  Are they reliable enough (assuming you're willing to run a fairly recent version of MySQL) or too bleeding-edge or expensive?

Lastly, does anyone have experience with something like the following use case and did you use savepoints for it?  Say the main point of some specific unit of work is to add a row to an `Orders` table (or whatever, doesn't have to be order-related, of course) and update an `OrdersAuditInfo` table, in the same transaction.  It is essential that `Orders` be updated if at all possible, but `OrdersAuditInfo` table is not as essential (e.g., it's ok to just log an error to a file, but keep going with the overall transaction).  At a low level it might look like this (warning, pseudo-SQL follows):

```
BEGIN;

INSERT INTO Orders(...) VALUES (...);
/* Do stuff outside of SQL here; if there are problems, do a
 ROLLBACK and report an error (i.e., Order is invalid in this
 case anyway). */

SAVEPOINT InsertAudit;
INSERT INTO OrdersAudit(...) VALUES(...);
/* If the INSERT fails, log an error to a log file somewhere and do: */
ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT InsertAudit;

/* Always want to commit the INSERT INTO Orders: */
COMMIT;
```

But even here perhaps there'd be a better (or at least more common) idiom?  One could do the `OrdersAuditInfo` insert in a completely different transaction but it would be nice to be guaranteed that the `OrdersAuditInfo` table were **not** written to unless the final `COMMIT` actually worked.

Answer (score 1):

I generally tend to avoid SAVEPOINTs, as it can make code quite hard to understand and verify.

In the case you posted, wrapping in a single transaction will depend on whether having `OrdersAudit` records exactly corresponding with `Orders`, is part of your business rules.

EDIT: Just re-read your question, and you do not have a requirement for guaranteed correspondence between `OrdersAudit` and `Orders`. So I wouldn't use any transaction for the insertion of the `OrdersAudit` records.

Comment: The reason why I wanted the OrdersAudit to be part of the overall transaction was in the case where the insert into Orders failed at COMMIT time for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are using a savepoint to avoid failed `INSERT`s to rollback the whole transaction. But in that case, the best way to do so is to use `INSERT IGNORE`. If it fails you will get a warning instead of an error, and nothing will rollback.

Since you don't need a rollback, I suggest you don't use a transaction.

`SAVEPOINT`s are great if you may want to rollback some successful statements (but not all statements). For example:

1. START TRANSACTION;
2. Relatively slow query that you don't want to run often
3. INSERT INTO a
4. SAVEPOINT one;
5. SELECT id INTO @id FROM slot WHERE status = 'free' ORDER BY timestamp LIMIT 1;
6. INSERT INTO b (slot_id, ...) VALUES (@id, ...)
7. INSERT INTO c (slot_id, ...) VALUES (@id, ...)
8. INSERT INTO d (slot_id, ...) VALUES (@id, ...)
9. COMMIT;

If the `SELECT` returns nothing, you may run a global `ROLLBACK`. If any of the following INSERTs fails, you may `ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT one` and pick another `id`. Obviously, in a case like this, you want to implement a maximum number of attempts in your code.